# Positive linear operator inequality

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm stuck proving the following inequality. Let $H$ autohermitian operator such that
$$\langle u|H|u\rangle\geq0\qquad\forall |u\rangle$$
Proof that
$$|\langle u|H|v\rangle|^2\leq\langle u|H|u\rangle\langle v|H|v\rangle$$
with equality $\langle u|H|u\rangle=0$ if $H|u\rangle =0$.

Can you help me with an idea please?

Comment: You may start from <(u+v)|H|(u+v)> ≥ 0. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tríed, but I don't know how obtain that inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This is Cauchy-Schwarz for the positive form $$[x,y]=\langle x|H|y\rangle.$$ Just use or repeat the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz.